# How to allow "0" value in date derived column in SSIS package

Tags: ssis

In SSIS package I am using a flat file source with a date column and some of the dates are with **0** value. The date column format is `YYYYMMDD` and I am converting this to `YYYY-MM-DD` format in derived column. If the date exists, the date is converting, but getting error for the date if it has **0**.  source file date datatype is `DT_STR` and destination SQL table field datatype is `smalldatetime`.

Please suggest logic for allowing the zero value in the derived column. I am using below logic.

```
[Date] == 0 ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([Date],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Date],5,2) + "-" + RIGHT([Date],2))
```

Comment: The data type of your column is a string. try [date] == "0" ? .....

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace (DT_Date) with (DT_DBDATE) ?

> [Date] == 0 ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : ...

Comment: Hi Nick, I am getting error derived column datatypes "DT_WSTR" and "DT_I4" are incompatible for binary operator "==".

Comment: @Venkat Your error is because you are trying to compare a string to an integer. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing data types. [Date] is a string and can't be compared to 0.

Try this:

```
[Date] == "0" ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)   (SUBSTRING([Date],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Date],5,2) + "-" + RIGHT([Date],2))
```